# Ошибка при установке библиотеки pyscf

Tags: python, pip

Не могу установить библиотеку pyscf, выводит ошибку:

```
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for pyscf (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [12 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      cmake -SC:\Users\Сергей\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-v89x28gq\pyscf_97a00ea7748c45b98188d92ee4e9f051\pyscf\lib -Bbuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-38\Release
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "c:\users\сергей\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
          return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
        File "c:\users\сергей\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
          exec(code, run_globals)
        File "C:\Users\Сергей\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\cmake.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cmake'
      error: command 'C:\\Users\\Сергей\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\Scripts\\cmake.exe' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyscf
Failed to build pyscf
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyscf, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Comment: `cmake.exe` не может найти, пишет